# sam package and deploy without packaged parameter file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

Our sam package command is -

```
sam package --template-file template.YML --output-template-file packaged-service.yml --s3-bucket $Template_Bucket_Name --s3-prefix service-build-$packagenumber
```

sam deploy command is -

```
sam deploy packaged-service.yml --stack-name service --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM --region us-east-1 --s3-bucket $Template_Bucket_Name --s3-prefix service-deploy-$packagenumber --template-file template.YML --parameter-overrides  "ParameterKey=EnvType,ParameterValue=ftest" --no-fail-on-empty-changeset
```

What is significance of packaged-service.yml file ? I can run deploy without it. So what purpose it fulfils ? Official package and deploy page are not clear about it.
packaged-service.yml has a codeuri field points to s3 bucket. In the above example, probably the file has no use ?
How to use metadata option during aws sam deploy command ?

Comment: May I know what you did finally?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of the SAM CLI, [then this `package` step is now implicitly performed when you do a deploy.](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/a-simpler-deployment-experience-with-aws-sam-cli/)

In earlier versions of SAM, the `package` step was needed if your lambda functions required dependencies to be packaged up into an archive.  It wasn't 100% necessary as if your Lambda was a single python file then you could go straight to `deploy`.
Since most SAM projects are more complex, the `package` helped by packaging your project into an archive, uploading your artifacts to S3 and then re-writing your SAM yaml to reference the new S3 location where the artifacts were uploaded.

I think the AWS team eventually saw that this package step was a little redundant and almost always performed before a deploy so [they streamlined the process with an update made in November 2019](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-sam-cli-simplifies-deploying-serverless-applications-with-single-command-deploy/) which made the process much simpler.

The `package` command is still included for backwards compatibility and to allow more flexibility if some teams still desire a multi-stage build and deploy process.

Comment: In this case, based on the subit example, what will happen for "--output-template-file packaged-service.yml "??? How we can avoid it?